# Centering 3 divs with dynamic height not working

Tags: html, css

The child divs must be centered vertically and horizontaly.

The parent height will must be auto and overflow children.

I have tryed both absulote and relative, looked at many examples, nothing works for my situation.

http://jsfiddle.net/uLktmwe3/4/

```
<div class="par1">paragraph1 paragraph1 paragraph1</div>
<div class="par2">paragraph2 paragraph2 paragraph2</div>
<div class="par3">
```

par3 can have many lines and so the parents height will be relative to him.

Expected outcome:

[image: outcome]

Comment: can you post an image how your alignment should look like?

Comment: very simple... par2 should be centered horizonticly. par1 and 2 should be centered vertically..

Comment: need little clarity,if par1 n2 are more than size of par3 then how your design wil look like?you wil get horizontal scroll for par2 n v ertical scroll for par1 ,am i correct?

Comment: Someone already answered right... no so dificult to undestand, take a look at the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want it?

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.frame {    
    border: 2px solid #918c91;    
    width: 100%;    
   padding: 10px;  
    border-radius: 28px;
    -moz-border-radius: 28px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
}
.par1,
.par2,
.par3{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0 1%;
}
.par3{   
    width: 54%;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
            
                <div class="par1">paragraph1 paragraph1 paragraph1</div><!--
                --><div class="par2">paragraph2 paragraph2 paragraph2</div><!--
                --><div class="par3">                 paragraph3paragraph3paragraph3p aragraph3paragraph3paragraph 3paragraph3paragraph3paragraph3paragraph3  paragraph3paragraph3paragraph 3paragraph3paragraph3paragraph3pa ragraph3paragraph3paragraph3paragraph3  paragraph3paragraph3paragra ph3paragraph3paragraph3paragrap h3paragraph3paragraph3par agraph3paragraph3
     </div>
           
        </div>
```

Comment: I tried adding 'float:right' to par3 and the vertical-align:middle stoped working. why is that?

Comment: Its a must for me to align left full page, what approach should i take then?

Comment: Thats the only solution, no option to use something like float right? also do you know of a good tutorial for centering? both relative and absolute, I see I am lacking in this area

Answer (score 0):

Please check following code 
css :-

```
    .frame {
    float:left;
    border-radius: 28px 28px 28px 28px;
    -moz-border-radius: 28px 28px 28px 28px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 28px 28px 28px 28px;
    border: 2px solid #918c91;
    width:90vw; height:auto; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;  word-wrap:break-word; overflow: hidden;
}

.par1{
    float:left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 45px;
    /* top: 50%; */    
    /* transform: translateY(-50%); */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-left:35px;
}

.par2{
    float:left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 63px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    /* top: 50%; */
    /* transform: translateY(-50%); */
    padding-left:55px;
    padding-right:55px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.par3{
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    width: 10vw;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding-left:55px;
}


http://jsfiddle.net/uLktm
```

we3/5/